# scraping table from wikipedia: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'

Tags: datatable, screen-scraping, wikipedia

I'm trying to get the table with the number of medals each country won at the last Olympic Games.

I tried using `find_all`:

```
import pandas
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
website_text = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2016_Summer_Olympics_medal_table').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(website_text,'xml')
​
table = soup.find_all('table',{'class':'wikitable sortable'})
table_rows = table.find('tr')
```

This returns `AttributeError: 'Nonetype' object has no attribute 'find_all'`. What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this piece of code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

website_text = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2016_Summer_Olympics_medal_table').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(website_text,'html.parser')

table = soup.find_all('tr')

print len(table)
```

Output: 110

Answer (score 0):

I would use pandas to get the table

```
import pandas as pd

table = pd.read_html('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2016_Summer_Olympics_medal_table')[1]
print(table)
```